# Blank Devices page in Ubuntu SDK IDE (Qt Creator)

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, ubuntu-emulator

I've installed Ubuntu SDK as per [this guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/), but now I want to add an Ubuntu Touch emulator, however the Devices page in the IDE is blank, see screen capture:

[image: IDE blank]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm exactly in the same condition... blank devices page/Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.
When launching qtcreator from terminal I got an error trace:

**file:///usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/qml/devicespage.qml:2:1: module "Ubuntu.Components" version 1.0 is not installed**

It seems that there is already a ticket of this problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-touch-meta/+bug/1419072

---

```
~$ qtcreator
    void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Follow Symbol Under Cursor" under id 187 
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/qml/devicespage.qml:2:1: module "Ubuntu.Components" version 1.0 is not installed 
         import Ubuntu.Components 1.0
         ^ 
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/qml/publishpage.qml:2:1: module "Ubuntu.Components" version 1.0 is not installed 
         import Ubuntu.Components 1.0 
         ^ 
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/welcomescreen/widgets/SessionItem.qml:51: ReferenceError: projectNameText is not defined
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/welcomescreen/develop.qml:93: ReferenceError: pageCaption is not defined
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/welcomescreen/widgets/PageLoader.qml:46: TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of null
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/welcomescreen/widgets/PageLoader.qml:46: TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of null
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/welcomescreen/widgets/PageLoader.qml:46: TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of null
    "application/x-goproject" 
    "application/x-goproject" 
    No go tool chain set from kit "Desktop".
    No go tool chain set from kit "UbuntuSDK for armhf (GCC ubuntu-sdk-14.10-utopic)".
    No go tool chain set from kit "Desktop".
    No go tool chain set from kit "UbuntuSDK for armhf (GCC ubuntu-sdk-14.10-utopic)".
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/welcomescreen/widgets/SessionItem.qml:51: ReferenceError: projectNameText is not defined
    file:///usr/share/qtcreator/welcomescreen/develop.qml:93: ReferenceError: pageCaption is not defined
    QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once.
    load glyph failed err=6 face=0xe8cd00, glyph=2797
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. And today's update for ubuntu sdk has fixed the problem.